# MongoDB filling missing results

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Within my aggregation pipeline, I get to the point where I may get the following intermediate documents:

```
{ date: "01-01-2018", value: 1 }
{ date: "04-01-2018", value: 2 }
{ date: "07-01-2018", value: 3 }
```

Depending on the data I have, I may get (as shown above) missing data points

Is there a way in my aggregation pipeline to provide some default documents (or default values like nulls) for the missing days?

Such that I'd get:

```
{ date: "01-01-2018", value: 1 }
{ date: "02-01-2018", value: null }
{ date: "03-01-2018", value: null }
{ date: "04-01-2018", value: 2 }
{ date: "05-01-2018", value: null }
{ date: "06-01-2018", value: null }
{ date: "07-01-2018", value: 3 }
```

Maybe $addToSet operator, but how can I add those artificial docs?

Is filling the gaps in business logic the only way?

Answer (score 3):

Starting in `Mongo 5.1`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$densify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-densify) aggregation operator:

```
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-01"), value: 1 }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-04"), value: 2 }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-07"), value: 3 }
db.test.aggregate([
  { $densify: {
    field: "date",
    range: { step: 1, unit: "day", bounds: "full" }
  }}
])
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-01"), value: 1 }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-02") }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-03") }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-04"), value: 2 }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-05") }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-06") }
// { date: ISODate("2018-01-07"), value: 3 }
```

---

This densifies documents ([`$densify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-densify)) by creating new documents in a sequence of documents where certain values for a `field` (in our case `field: "date"`) are missing:

- the step for our densification is 1 day: `range: { step: 1, unit: "day", ... }`
- and we densify within the range of dates defined by our documents: `bounds: "full"`

---

Of course, to make this work with your specific example, you can switch from dates to strings with [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)  and back to dates with [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {"$addFields":{ "datefield":"$datefield"}}, 
])
```

I think this will add null values if the field does not exist in a document.
  However artificial docs cannot be added in mongo.